# Covariant derivative commutes with partial derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, connections

I'm trying to understand the proof of Proposition 2.4 in Chapter 9 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. There's a part that I'm unsure of where, "by the symmetry of the Riemannian connection", he uses
$$\frac{D}{dt}\frac{df}{ds}=\frac{D}{ds}\frac{df}{dt},$$
where $f:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times [0,1]\to M$ is a variation of the curve $c:[0,1]\to M$. The symmetry of the connection means
$$\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX=[X,Y],$$
so I tried to justify his use of the first formula by first writing
$$\frac{D}{dt}\frac{df}{ds}=\nabla_{\partial f/\partial t}\left(\frac{df}{ds}\right),$$
then saying
$$\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\right]=0,$$
and so
$$\frac{D}{dt}\frac{df}{ds}=\nabla_{\partial f/\partial t}\left(\frac{df}{ds}\right)=\nabla_{\partial f/\partial s}\left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)=\frac{D}{ds}\frac{df}{dt}.$$
I know this is a simple thing; I just want to make sure that it's correct. Thanks.

Comment: What does D represent in D/dt?

Comment: @timur $\frac{D}{dt},\frac{D}{ds}$ are covariant derivatives.

Comment: If you're using Do Carmo, then look at the chapter on geodesics. One of the lemmas proves precisely this. Edit: CHapter 3, Lemma 3.4 is the symmetry lemma. Btw, the issue with using Lie brackets is that these are not vector fields defined on an open subset of the manifold, rather they are just vector fields along $f$ (i.e they are smooth lifts of $f$ to $TM$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks!! I swear I looked in that chapter but somehow overlooked this lemma.

Comment: Aren't $df/dt$ and $df/ds$ just functions? Why do you need covariant derivatives?

Comment: @timur there's a lot going on here with notation. Here, $f:U\subset \Bbb{R}^2\to M$, so $\frac{df}{dt},\frac{df}{ds}$ are not correct notations. One should atleast write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$, but even this is imprecise (because it's not a limit of difference quotient of anything, since we can't add in manifolds) but it's tradition. What is meant is let $\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$ be the standard vector fields on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (i.e corresponding to $e_1,e_2$). Really, we're looking at their pushforwards via $f$.

Comment: So, they are maps of the type $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}:U\to TM$. Since they take values in the vector bundle $TM$, and are lifts of $f$, we can "differentiate along $f$" using the connection on $TM$ to get $\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ and so on (for various combinations of $s,t$).

Comment: Thanks! I understood it completely wrong and almost wrote an "answer" to a phantom question.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm aware that we're really looking at pushforwards, but don't we need $f$ a diffeomorphism to ensure these pushforwards are well-defined? Also, what exactly is the problem with taking the Lie bracket of vector fields along curves?

Comment: @Stuck this is a "pointwise pushforward". For each $p\in U$, we get a vector $f_{*,p}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_p\right)\in T_{f(p)}M$. Other notations include $Tf_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_p\right)\in T_{f(p)}M$. The reason you're thinking of the diffeomorphism requirement is that if $X$ is a vector field on a manifold $N$ and $f:N\to M$ is a smooth map, then to get a vector field on $M$, pushforward is $Tf\circ X\circ f^{-1}$, hence we need the diffeomorphism requirement.

Comment: But like I said above, the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$  are NOT vector fields on $M$ (i.e they're not smooth maps $M\to TM$ such that $\pi\circ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\text{id}_M$). They're not sections of $TM$. These are all different ways of saying the same thing. All we have is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ denotes a vector field **along $f$**. Meaning $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}:U\subset\Bbb{R}^2\to TM$ satisfies $\pi\circ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=f$. Finally, regarding Lie brackets:the definition requires two vector fields defined on an open subset of a manifold

Comment: @peek-a-boo So it seems like what you're calling the pointwise pushforward, in both cases (i.e. $f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$ and $f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right)$), defines a vector field along $f$ (i.e. a section of the pullback bundle $f^*TM$). Is this correct?

Comment: @Stuck yes. In general if $(E,\pi,M)$ is a vector bundle and $f:N\to M$ is a smooth map, then a vector field along $f$ is a map $\phi:N\to E$ such that $\pi\circ \phi=f$... i.e a smooth lift of $f$. This can indeed be identified with a section of the pullback bundle $f^*E\to N$, because $f^*E=\{(x,\xi)\in N\times E\,:\, f(x)=\pi(\xi)\}$. So a section of this bundle is a mapping $\Phi:N\to f^*(E)\subset N\times E$, which is of the form $\Phi(x)=(x,\phi(x))$ for some $\phi:N\to E$ such that $\pi\circ \phi=f$. Here, we're looking at $E=TM$.